# stop style validations from Angular-auto-validate plug-in

Tags: angularjs

I am working on an angular application where we are using this [[Angular-Auto-Validate]](http://jonsamwell.github.io/angular-auto-validate/) plug for form validations. This plug-in works automattically with all type of form validation which is quiet easy to use but we are facing an issue with this.

We want to stop validate to bootstrap style validations. It keeps us giving this error message.

```
Angular-auto-validate: invalid bs3 form structure elements must be wrapped by a form-group class
```

as per the plug-in documentation we added this few configurations but seems like we are doing something wrong.

```
validator.setValidElementStyling(false);
validator.setInvalidElementStyling(false);
```

Comment: Hola tengo el mismo problema encontraron la solución

Answer (score 2):

This will be resolved if you place all your form inputs inside a form-group class. here is example.

```
  <div class="form-group">
      <input type="text"........../>
 </div>
```